# How to get warnings() output to string

Tags: r, logging, error-handling, try-catch, warnings

When I type warnings() to console, I get back

```
Warning message:
In fread(my_directory,  ... :
 C function strtod() returned ERANGE for one or more fields. The first was string input    '4.40589099726375E-309'. It was read using (double)strtold() as numeric
```

However when I type `as.character(warnings())`, I get:

```
[1] "fread(my_directory)"
```

My objective is to get the *actual* message displayed in warning() into a character string, so that I can pass it to the `logwarn` function in the `logging` package. Currently, I am doing `logwarn(warnings(),logger="some_log_file.log")` to record my warnings, but it gives the incorrect coercion to `character` that I displayed above.

Note that I can just use `sink` but I want to stick with `logging` package, so I require the ability to correct coerce to `character`.

Comment: `capture.output(warnings())` or `paste(capture.output(warnings()), collapse = "\n")` for your purpose?

Comment: @lukeA Does this work if there are multiple warnings?

Comment: yep - it captures all output.

Answer (score 6):

This may not be the exact answer you're looking for, but I think it's worth a mention.

R has a global variable, `last.warning`, which holds just that, the last warning.  Calling `names` on it will return the last warning as a character string.  Here's a little example

First, purposely trigger a warning:

```
x <- 1:5
if(x == 1) "yes" else "no"
# [1] "yes"
# Warning message:
# In if (x == 1) "yes" else "no" :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Look at the variable `last.warning`:

```
last.warning
# $`the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`
# if (x == 1) "yes" else "no"
```

Now look at the `names(last.warning)`.  This returns the warning as a character string:

```
names(last.warning)
# [1] "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"
```

Comment: This is great! `names(last.warning)` together with `toString(last.warning)` keeps all the warning information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`warnings()` returns a list. 
The list values are the language elements which produced the warning; that is what you are seeing with `as.character()`. 
The names of the list values are the warning messages. You can get those with `names(warnings())`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a calling handler along with the 'restart' (see ?warning and ?withCallingHandlers) that warning() creates

```
f = function() { warning("oops"); 1 }

withCallingHandlers({
    f()
}, warning=function(cond) {
    txt <- conditionMessage(cond)
    ## do with txt what you will, e.g.,
    ## logwarn(txt, logger="some_log_file.log")
    message("captured warning: ", txt, "; now continuing")
    ## signal that the warning has been handled
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

Comment: This is overly complicated and does not even work in situations where you want to use the warning message in the surrounding scope. You would need to define `txt` outside and use `txt <<- `.