# How to control R warnings in knitr to rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, warnings, knitr

I have a chunk with a loop which produces images and results of a linear model. Sometimes the model produces non-convergence warnings. Images and results become fully disorganised if I let `warning=TRUE` as chunk condition. But I want to print the warning, so I try it through
`cat(names(last.warning))` (thanks to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25327596/997979)). Then I get the next error when `knitr`:

```r
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'last.warning' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Execution halted
```

What can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to try to catch the warning and print its message. The following example is inside a `suppressWarnings` call, which should have the same effect as being inside a `warning = FALSE` chunk.

Here the actual code I want to run is just `as.numeric(c("1", "A"))`. I want to print any warnings the code generates despite it being inside a `suppressWarnings` block, and I also want to print the result of the code:

```r
suppressWarnings({

#--- Code chunk ----------------------------------------------------------#  
  
  withCallingHandlers(
        expr    = as.numeric(c("1", "A")), 
        warning = function(w) cat("** warning:", w$message, "**\n\n")
  )

#--- End of code chunk ---------------------------------------------------#

})

#> ** warning: NAs introduced by coercion **
#> 
#> [1]  1 NA
```

---

**Edit**

Here is a reproducible Rmd that shows how to display any warnings optionally after the result of the calculation is printed:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Allan Cameron"
date: "27 November 2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
 ```

 ## Print warning after output

 ```{r test, warning=FALSE}
   withCallingHandlers(
        expr    = as.numeric(c("1", "A")), 
        warning = function(w) warn <<- paste("** warning:", w$message, "**\n\n")
   )
```

```{r print_warn, echo=FALSE}
  if(exists("warn")) cat(warn)
```
````

This produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I try it and get a result like yours, fine. But I get the warning printed always above the expression. If I try to save `w$message` in a variable, using either `<-` or `<<-` and I try to print after the `withCallingHandlers` I also get an `object not found` error. Is it possible to do something?

Comment: Thank you! I have a new related (on the handling warnings side) question. Can you take a look?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035226/is-there-a-way-to-use-trycatch-or-similar-in-r-as-a-loop-or-to-manipulate-the