# Is there a way to use tryCatch (or similar) in R as a loop, or to manipulate the expr in the warning argument?

Tags: r, exception, try-catch, warnings

I have a regression model (`lm` or `glm` or `lmer` ...) and I do `fitmodel <- lm(inputs)` where `inputs` changes inside a loop (the formula and the data). Then, if the model function does not produce any warning I want to keep `fitmodel`, but if I get a warning I want to `update` the model and I want the warning **not** printed, so I do `fitmodel <- lm(inputs)` inside `tryCatch`. So, if it produces a warning, inside `warning = function(w){f(fitmodel)}`, `f(fitmodel)` would be something like

```r
fitmodel <- update(fitmodel, something suitable to do on the model)
```

In fact, this assignation would be inside an `if-else` structure in such a way that depending on the warning `if(w$message satisfies something)` I would adapt the `suitable to do on the model` inside `update`.

The problem is that I get `Error in ... object 'fitmodel' not found`. If I use `withCallingHandlers` with `invokeRestarts`, it just finishes the computation of the model with the warning without `update` it. If I add again `fitmodel <- lm(inputs)` inside `something suitable to do on the model`, I get the warning printed; now I think I could try `suppresswarnings(fitmodel <- lm(inputs))`, but yet I think it is not an elegant solution, since I have to add 2 times the line `fitmodel <- lm(inputs)`, making 2 times all the computation (inside `expr` and inside `warning`).

Summarising, what I would like but fails is:

```r
tryCatch(expr = {fitmodel <- lm(inputs)},
         warning = function(w) {if (w$message satisfies something) {
                                    fitmodel <- update(fitmodel, something suitable to do on the model)
                                } else if (w$message satisfies something2){
                                    fitmodel <- update(fitmodel, something2 suitable to do on the model)

                                }
         }
)
```

What can I do?

The loop part of the question is because I thought it like follows (maybe is another question, but for the moment I leave it here): it can happen that after the `update` I get another warning, so I would do something like `while(get a warning on update){update}`; in some way, this `update` inside `warning` should be understood also as `expr`. Is something like this possible?

Thank you very much!

---

*Generic version of the question with minimal example:*

Let's say I have a `tryCatch(expr = {result <- operations}, warning = function(w){f(...)}` and if I get a warning in `expr` (produced in fact in `operations`) I want to do something with `result`, so I would do `warning = function(w){f(result)}`, but then I get `Error in ... object 'result' not found`.

A minimal example:

```r
y <- "a"
tryCatch(expr = {x <- as.numeric(y)},
    warning = function(w) {print(x)})
Error in ... object 'x' not found
```

I tried using `withCallingHandlers` instead of `tryCatch` without success, and also using `invokeRestart` but it does the expression part, not what I want to do when I get a warning.

Could you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, fundamentally, is that the handler is called before the assignment happens. And even if that weren’t the case, the handler runs in a different scope than the `tryCatch` expression, so the handler can’t access the names in the other scope.

We need to separate the handling from the value transformation.

For errors (but not warnings), base R provides the function `try`, which wraps `tryCatch` to achieve this effect. However, using `try` is discouraged, because its return type is [unsound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).<sup>1</sup> As mentioned [in the answer by ekoam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036715/1968), ‘purrr’ provides soundly typed [functional wrappers](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html) (e.g. `safely`) to achieve a similar effect.

However, we can also build our own, which might be a better fit in this situation:

```
with_warning = function (expr) {
    self = environment()
    warning = NULL

    result = withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function (w) {
        self$warning = w
        tryInvokeRestart('muffleWarning')
    })
    list(result = result, warning = warning)
}
```

This gives us a wrapper that distinguishes between the result value and a warning. We can now use it to implement your requirement:

```
fitmodel = with(with_warning(lm(inputs)), {
    if (! is.null(warning)) {
        if (conditionMessage(warning) satisfies something) {
            update(result, something suitable to do on the model)
        } else {
            update(result, something2 suitable to do on the model)
        }
    } else {
        result
    }
})
```

---

<sup>1</sup> What this means is that `try`’s return type doesn’t distinguish between an error and a non-error value of type `try-error`. This is a real situation that can occur, for example, when nesting multiple `try` calls.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are looking for a functional wrapper that captures both the returned value and side effects of a function call. I think `purrr::quietly` is a perfect candidate for this kind of task. Consider something like this

```
quietly <- purrr::quietly

foo <- function(x) {
  if (x < 3)
    warning(x, " is less than 3")
  if (x < 4)
    warning(x, " is less than 4")
  x
}

update_foo <- function(x, y) {
  x <- x + y
  foo(x)
}

keep_doing <- function(inputs) {
  out <- quietly(foo)(inputs)
  repeat {
    if (length(out$warnings) < 1L)
      return(out$result)
    
    cat(paste0(out$warnings, collapse = ", "), "\n")
    # This is for you to see the process. You can delete this line.
    
    if (grepl("less than 3", out$warnings[[1L]])) {
      out <- quietly(update_foo)(out$result, 1.5)
    } else if (grepl("less than 4", out$warnings[[1L]])) {
      out <- quietly(update_foo)(out$result, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
> keep_doing(1)
1 is less than 3, 1 is less than 4 
2.5 is less than 3, 2.5 is less than 4 
[1] 4

> keep_doing(3)
3 is less than 4 
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like the following? If it is run with `y <- "123"`, the `"OK"` message will be printed.

```
y <- "a"
#y <- "123"
x <- tryCatch(as.numeric(y),
              warning = function(w) w
)
if(inherits(x, "warning")){
  message(x$message)
} else{
  message(paste("OK:", x))
}
```

It's easier to test several argument values with the code above rewritten as a function.

```
testWarning <- function(x){
  out <- tryCatch(as.numeric(x),
                  warning = function(w) w
  )
  if(inherits(out, "warning")){
    message(out$message)
  } else{
    message(paste("OK:", out))
  }
  invisible(out)
}

testWarning("a")
#NAs introduced by coercion
testWarning("123")
#OK: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could assign `x` again in the handling condition?

```
tryCatch(
  warning = function(cnd) {
    x <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(y))
    print(x)},
  expr = {x <- as.numeric(y)}
)
#> [1] NA
```

Perhaps not the most elegant answer, but solves your toy example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the assignment in the `tryCatch` call, put it outside.  For example,

```
y <- "a"
x <- tryCatch(expr = {as.numeric(y)},
    warning = function(w) {y})
```

This assigns `y` to `x`, but you could put anything in the warning body, and the result will be assigned to `x`.

Your "what I would like" example is more complicated, because you want access to the `expr` value, but it hasn't been assigned anywhere at the time the warning is generated.  I think you'll have to recalculate it:

```
fitmodel <- tryCatch(expr = {lm(inputs)},
         warning = function(w) {if (w$message satisfies something) {
                                    update(lm(inputs), something suitable to do on the model)
                                } else if (w$message satisfies something2){
                                    update(lm(inputs), something2 suitable to do on the model)

                                }
         }
)
```

Edited to add:

To allow the evaluation to proceed to completion before processing the warning, you can't use `tryCatch`. The `evaluate` package has a function (also called `evaluate`) that can do this.  For example,

```
y <- "a"
res <- evaluate::evaluate(quote(x <- as.numeric(y)))
for (i in seq_along(res)) {
    if (inherits(res[[i]], "warning") && 
        conditionMessage(res[[i]]) == gettext("NAs introduced by coercion",
                                              domain = "R"))
        x <- y
}
```

Some notes:  the `res` list will contain lots of different things, including messages, warnings, errors, etc.  My code only looks at the warnings.  I used `conditionMessage` to extract the warning message, but
it will be translated to the local language, so you should use `gettext` to translate the English version of the message for comparison.

Comment: I put the assignment inside `tryCatch` because I would like to use later inside the `warning` argument and I am asking if there is possible.

Comment: I think it is not possible using base R code, other than duplicating the calculation as in my answer.  R code has access to the warning message or the expression value, but not both.  However, the `evaluate::evaluate()` function can do it; I'll add an example.