# Is it possible to handle simple messages in R? If yes, how?

Tags: r, exception, try-catch

To handle warnings or errors one can use

```r
result = tryCatch({
    expr
}, warning = function(w) {
    warning-handler-code
}, error = function(e) {
    error-handler-code
}, finally = {
    cleanup-code
}
```

but if expr gives a `message` through `simpleMessage`, how can I get it? Is there something like?:

```r
message = function(m) {message-handler-code}
```

Or another function which allows me to capture the message?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `message =`  just as you can with `warning` and `error`:

```r
result = tryCatch({
    message("Hello world")
    1 + 1
}, message = function(m) {m}
)

result
#> <simpleMessage in message("Hello world"): Hello world
>
```

It's more likely however that you would want to capture your result and message separately:

```r
result <- withCallingHandlers({
    message("Hello world")
    1 + 1
}, message = function(m) {
    lastMessage <<- m
    invokeRestart("muffleMessage")
})

result
#> [1] 2

if(exists("lastMessage")) message(lastMessage)
#> Hello world
```

Comment: Neat, our thoughts converged.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, very nice exposition you have there. Yours is the better answer in didactic terms and I hope it is accepted by the OP. I still feel a little queasy at stashing a variable in the calling environment as a side-effect, and did wonder if there was a better way. It's kind of reassuring to see you doing the same thing (although I suppose you are explicitly creating the cache first, rather than testing for existence afterwards).

Comment: If it’s properly encapsulated there’s nothing to be queasy about, it’s a common enough pattern when working with closures. R6 does the same as a core part of its implementation. However, I’ve used `<<-` only for brevity, in my own code I never use it. Instead, I define a reference to the enclosing environment (simply, `self = environment()` inside `with_logging`) and then perform assignment via `self$messages = c(messages, msg)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph also, I struggled to find a listing of available restarts, even in the R source code. The documentation is pretty brief. You don't know of an easy way to list them by any chance?

Comment: I don’t think such a list exists, unfortunately. You can enumerate them — see the source code of `findRestart` — but since they’re dynamically created, this won’t work except inside a condition handler. To find the relevant, defined restarts, you have to read the code of the condition signaller to find out which restarts are installed by `withRestarts` — in this case, inside `message`. I assume you already did that. That said, the documentation of `message` *does* mention this restart. Other condition help pages do too.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes (well actually I found it inside `suppressMessages`). I guess the body of `withRestarts` is where I should be looking. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much both! All this is completely new for me, the documentation in R is quite dark and online explanations in blogs or whatever are poor. Or were; until now. ;)

Comment: Please note that `invokeRestart("muffleMessage")` will throw an error for the class `simpleMessage` as returned by `simpleMessage(...)`... So I would do `if (findRestart(...) invokeRestart(...)` instead

Answer (score 2):

`tryCatch` is the most commonly useful solution for handling conditions.

However, `tryCatch` *aborts* execution and returns the value of the handler, rather than resuming execution of the code. This may not always be what you want; sometimes you want to handle a condition and carry on.

R allows this thanks to its [incredibly powerful condition system](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html).

For example, you can choose to *silence* all messages:

```
suppressMessages(expr)
```

The nice thing here is that the `suppressMessages` isn’t magic — it’s a plain old R function and you could write it yourself (but you do need to understand the condition system, and the price for its versatility is that it’s fairly complicated).

To illustrate this, here’s another way of handling messages — using `withCallingHandlers` — which suppresses the messages, carries on executing the code it’s called with, but at the same time logs the message in a list:

```
messages = list()

withCallingHandlers({
    message('Hello world')
    1 + 1
}, message = function (msg) {
    messages <<- c(messages, msg)
    tryInvokeRestart('muffleMessage')
})
```

`tryInvokeRestart('muffleMessage')` is the same method by which `suppressMessages` works. The only difference is that we added code to store the message.

As a last step, the above can even be wrapped inside a function:

```
with_logging = function (expr) {
    messages = list()

    log_message = function (msg) {
        messages <<- c(messages, conditionMessage(msg))
        tryInvokeRestart('muffleMessage')
    }

    result = withCallingHandlers(expr, message = log_message)
    list(result = result, messages = messages)
}
```

And to use it:

```
with_logging({
    message('this is a test')
    1 + 1
})
```

```
$result
[1] 2

$messages
$messages[[1]]
[1] "this is a test\n"
```

Comment: If you like to copy and paste your answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035226/is-there-a-way-to-use-trycatch-or-similar-in-r-as-a-loop-or-to-manipulate-the I would accept it there, since you have given me the idea to do the loop